# Being prompted for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 redistributable package repeatedly

Tags: visual-c++, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to run a setup file and am continuously getting the error that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable package is required. I downloaded the package and installed, but it didn't work out. We also tried to uninstall/reinstall and restart the server but its still the same.

The package that we downloaded was from the following links :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14632
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Requesting help on the same.

OS - Windows Server 2008 SP2 - 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You must install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632).

Comment: I did. I downloaded it from "http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14632", but it didn't work out. Anything else you would like to suggest?

Comment: Download it from new Below Link:(it is cracked and tested)
if it want password use : "www.softgozar.com"
http://dl.softgozar.com/Files/Software/Microsoft_Visual_C_2008_SP1_Redistributable_Package_x64_softgozar.com.exe

Comment: I appreciate the link, but this link is for Visual C++ 2008, what I'm looking for is 2010. Do you have a cracked version for 2010?